# Check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ECDL AND anno_formativo = 2015-16' at line 1

Tags: php

i have a problem with this string...can you help me, please?

$sql_corso = "SELECT `titolo_corso`, `anno_formativo` FROM `tbl_corsi` WHERE `titolo_corso` = ".$titolo_corso." AND anno_formativo = ".$anno_formativo."";

Comment: `$sql_corso = "SELECT titolo_corso, anno_formativo FROM tbl_corsi WHERE titolo_corso = $titolo_corso AND anno_formativo = $anno_formativo";`

Comment: $sql_corso = 'SELECT titolo_corso, anno_formativo FROM tbl_corsi WHERE titolo_corso = "'. $titolo_corso.'"AND anno_formativo = "'.$anno_formativo.'"';

Comment: Are you sanitizing `$titolo_corso` and `$anno_formativo` before entering them into the query? Ie. escaping any single-quotes they may contain.

Comment: i have this new error: Unknown column '0000' in 'field list'

Comment: K, post more code or I can't help you. Please post your latest query `$sql_corso = ...` as well as any other relevant information/code. Where could '0000' be coming from? What variables holds '0000'? Why is that in your query? You know more about your query than I do. Please post your latest query.

Comment: $sql_corso = 'SELECT titolo_corso, anno_formativo FROM tbl_corsi WHERE titolo_corso = "'.$titolo_corso.'" AND anno_formativo = "'.$anno_formativo.'"';

Comment: Use this: `$sql_corso = "SELECT titolo_corso, anno_formativo FROM tbl_corsi WHERE titolo_corso = '". $titolo_corso ."' AND anno_formativo = '". $anno_formativo ."'";` per my answer below.

Comment: There is the same error as before

Comment: You've had 2 errors. Which one is it?

Comment: Yes, sorry.
There is : Unknown column '0000' in 'field list'

Comment: Do this for me please. Without it, I cannot help you any further: Please edit your original post with your new query, exactly as it stands in your script. Also, please post the values of `$titolo_corso` and `$anno_formativo` exactly as they are. Please do not edit anything. Post everything exactly as you see, in full. You still haven't address the `Unknown column '0000' in 'field list'` issue.

Comment: OK, just a minute and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add single-quotes to your (string-based) query values:

```
$sql_corso = "SELECT titolo_corso, anno_formativo FROM tbl_corsi WHERE titolo_corso = '". $titolo_corso ."' AND anno_formativo = '". $anno_formativo ."'";
```

Comment: Same error? Different error? If so, please post the new error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ECDL AND anno_formativo = 2015-16' at line 1

Comment: Can you post your updated query to your original post, as an edit? Post the exact one you're using right now. If you're receiving the exact same error as before, I'm wondering that you haven't actually updated your query.